# How to send data from Web Pages to Java program

Tags: java, html

How do I get the user input from a webpage and pass it to a java program?
Say I'm making a forum then I use HTML for creating a login page, I want the user input in the login fields to be sent to my Java function.

Ex:

```
void myfunc(String fromHTML){ //Store fromHTML in file } )
```

So basically how to send `User` data to my Java Functions?
I heard we can use PHP but I want to specifically use Java.

Comment: Do you already have a program that you want to send data to, or do you want to write a new program?

Answer (score -1):

Study [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/). You're clearly missing too much: Java Enterprise Edition provides the services you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can 'post' the data of your login form to a **Java servlet** which can then process the data. If you have no idea about servlets, you can get a basic idea about it from here

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html